# Why did Gradle 3.4.0 break my dependency?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

When I upgraded gradle to 3.4.0, it broke the dependency to our custom libraries in JFOG repository.

APP LEVEL

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' > classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.5'
```

MODULE LEVEL

```
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

dependencies {
    implementation "com.xxx.yyy:zzz:1.0.0@aar"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.xxx.yyy:zzz:1.0.0**

Therefore I am not able make a build. Any idea why?

Comment: Why do you have dependencies outside the `dependencies` block?

Comment: @Zoe Sorry for confusion, but no, I have it inside, I updated question.

Comment: have you tried to manually clean project? I know it sounds silly, but sometimes that's the case

Comment: Yes, I tried to clean and also "Invalidate cache/Restart".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by explicitly adding maven repository from context url, since apparently the `artifactory{...}` wasn't adding it.
Remember to add all other repositories in place of the three dots (normally `jcenter()` and `google()` are enough, but it depends on your project actual dependencies)

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/maven"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
       ...
}
```

Comment: I already have something like this:

    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    resolve {
        repository {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }

Comment: The `/maven` is necessary, since the actual maven repo is under `${contextUrl}/maven` - unless your maven repo isn't under another name (such as `maven-local`): in that case you need to specify _that_ name.
In fact `${contextUrl}` has no repo at that specific url.
Also note that the code in the answer isn't to be put under `artifactory {...}`, but at root level of the root `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution. It seems to be bug of Android Studio 3.4/3.5 and it was "fixed" by disabling:

**File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant**